# Executing Terminal commands using Python in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I want to change the IP address of the machine continuously, SO after a lot of search i got this useful link https://github.com/jotyGill/openpyn-nordvpn . I have done the steps as per this URL and i tried the steps in terminal window(Mac) and it is successfully changing the IP.

But the issue is that need to manually run the script again to change the IP, So thought of automating it.

So what i want to do is ,

```
1. Open an terminal window in mac using Python and execute the following commands,

Enter this command :
sudo openpyn --init

it will prompt to enter password and i have to enter password manually,Is there a way where the program can do this password input automatically using subprocess or any other methods in Python?

After the user name and password is entered ,Need to enter the below command.

openpyn US --area “area”

This will change the IP and need to do the same again.While doing the same either we need to do it from the start or pass CTRL+C to end the current execution and pass 
" openpyn US --area “area” "this command again.
```

I'm trying to execute few statements in terminal window from a python program.

These are the things i have done and no luck .Can anyone please guide me on how to do this?

```
import subprocess
import os
pid = os.fork()

os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "sudo openpyn --init;openpyn US --area “area”;os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)"'""")

subprocess.call(["sudo openpyn --init"], shell=True)

os.system("sudo openpyn --init")
```

Comment: If you are running a lot of terminal commands, it might be easier to write a [Shell Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html) instead which can also run your Python function.

Comment: @Jamie Can i input password and username through shell scripts? I only want to execute 2 to 3 commands ,Any guidance please.I have been into this for 4 days and till now haven't got a solution for this, Will be very helpful if you can guide or give some suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you need to enter your password. It's a sudo command, sudo requires password. Otherwise someone using your computer could literally do anything on it. Please read what `sudo` is.

Comment: @h4z3 I want this program or process to be automated, So ideally the password and all credentials should be passed from the program that is the issue i'm facing now. Is there anyway for this or any alternatives?

Comment: @h4z3 I want to create a python script to open a terminal and pass the above commands and pass the credentials if asked and automate that python script to execute every 15 minutes.This is my goal.Any suggestions on this on how i can achieve it?

Comment: Why do want a Terminal at all? Why don't you just have a shell script that runs continuously changing the IP address waiting some number of seconds then repeating? Or a `cron` job that runs every 2 minutes? You can add yourself, or a special new users to the `sudoers` file so that you can `sudo` with no password needed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The script i use will ask me to enter my VPN credentials username and password to enter not only the SUDO password.So this is causing an issue.

Comment: Ok, you can automate that with `expect`.... https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378

Comment: You can allow your single user to run a single program via `sudo` without a password like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18833

Comment: You can run your script every 15 minutes automatically with `launchctl` https://www.splinter.com.au/using-launchd-to-run-a-script-every-5-mins-on/

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a lot,Sure .I will check on it and will update here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually use mac but this might work:

```
import os
import time

os.system(Command)
time.sleep(0.25)
os.system(password)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).